# Error: A user access token is required to request this resource, while trying to post in user feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

**Problem- 1**

I want to post in user's wall but I'm getting sometimes: *A user access token is required to request this resource.*

Here is what I made:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);


$params = array(
                'access_token'  =>  $access_token,
                'link'          =>  "http://www.facebook.com/PaginaRomanilor?sk=app_".APP_ID,
                'message'       =>  $caption." - Amuză-ți și tu prietenii cu aplicația întrebări pentru prieteni.",
                'name'          =>  $caption,
                'description'   =>  'Răspuns: '.ucfirst($raspuns).'. '.$mesaj,
                'caption'       =>  'TS',
                'picture'       =>  LINK."images/".$raspuns.".png",
                'tags'          => $friendpost['uid'],
                'place'         => 155021662189
            );

        if(!($sendMessage = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$params))){
            $errors= error_get_last();
            echo "Facebook publish error: ".$errors['type'];
            echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
        }
```

When I personally use the app I don't get the error, only some users gets the error.

**Problem-2**

In the link, I'm providing the link to my page. The caption is ignored and is replaced by *Page: 7,726 like this.*

But I want to give the customized caption in that post.

**UPDATE:**

The user access token error was not from this part of code, it was from selecting friends database, so i resolved there, the problem i had now whi is my custom caption disabled and replaced with the likes of the page from link.

Comment: "A user access token is required to request this resource." There's some problem with the access token. Why are you setting the access token ?

Comment: I`m setting because the error: A user access token is required to request this resource. but the error is still here. Is it possible to be because of parameters? i read somewhere that someone did something wrong in parameters and because of this.

Comment: I made an update please read.

Answer (score 0):

You get a user access token when user logs into your application and authorizes it to do specific tasks. you can also ask for extended access token like this:-

```
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
```

to do the task on behalf of user in his/her absence.

As for your second problem, there is some peculiar issue about how the Facebook parses the link passed to it. Whenever it is a URL from Facebook's domain it overrides some parameters, disable some parameters and adds some values. And this is the case with the Page Tab application links which get the Likes count from the Page they are on.

There is one way although through which you can get a result to your liking, and it is to shorten the URL using any URL shortening service like [bit.ly](https://bitly.com/)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please review and update if you still face issue